# New Windows Store search API?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Now that Windows 10 has been released, Microsoft has updated their Windows Store (at least for people in the US -- international pages seem to still be in progress). Prior to this update, I used the API available at https://services.apps.microsoft.com/browse/6.2.9200-1/615/en-US_en-US/c/US/cp/10005001/Apps/[APPID] to grab info on apps. This API still works, except with two issues:

a) It works only with the "old" app ids -- there seem to be new app ids for apps in Windows Store

b) Many apps in Windows Store now don't show a price (e.g. they show N/A) when accessed via the web or API but do show a price when opened in Windows Store

Is there a new API that works with the newly updated Windows Store?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This guy has built an API, which, although I haven't tested it, should work on the new store:
http://blog.lionelchetty.co.za/an-api-for-you-wpdevs/

Comment: Any insights on how he built it?

Comment: Sorry, no. You could always contact him